# How to make the orginial website background of a navigation menu fixed and 100% wide?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-position

I have a responsive navigation menu and when you open it on a smartphone or tablet, the original background of the website gets fixed to prevent the user from scrolling:

```css
.cover-bg {
    position: fixed;
}
```

But this also results to the scrolling bar to be hidden and the whole background moves to the left.
This is not wanted and really weird, how can I fix this?

[Heres my website, open it on a smartphone and click on the menu.](https://antonrave.de)
(antonrave.de - Already fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
.cover-bg {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0; 
}
```